# How do I enable changes in /etc/lirc/lircrc without reboot

Tags: lirc

I have installed lirc, and I want to use irexec to control my music player daemon (mpd) using `mpc` commands from my mce remote control. Works fine, except for one thing:

If I want to edit the `/etc/lirc/lircrc` file to map the remote control buttons to commands, I need to reboot in order to read in and use the edited lircrc button/command definition file. To test things out is then a rather painful and time consuming experience.

```
/etc/init.d/lirc restart
```

does NOT do the trick, it just makes the remote stop working. Function returns after reboot.

What elese needs to be restarted? Or should I use some other method?

Comment: Did you try `service lirc restart`?

Comment: Yes I did try "service lirc restart". No change, the MCE remote just ceased to work, reboot fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Sending a HUP signal to the daemon makes it reread the config file.

Find daemon pid:

```
$ ps -elf | grep lircd
$ 1 S root      3198     1  0  80   0 -  4545 -      09:56 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/lircd --device=/dev/lirc0
```

Send the HUP signal:

```
$ sudo kill-HUP 3198
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not problem with

```
/etc/init.d/lirc restart
```

or

```
service lirc restart
```

that works fine. 
Problem is when lirc is going down during the restart - irexec going down to. 
So the simply solition is start irexec again

```
nohup irexec &
```