# Unable to stub 1 of 2 nvidia cards

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I am unable to have my video card claimed completely by stub:

```
[    9.897987] pci-stub: add 10DE:13C2 sub=FFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFF cls=00000000/00000000
[    9.897998] pci-stub: add 10DE:0FBB sub=FFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFF cls=00000000/00000000
[    9.898008] pci-stub 0000:01:00.1: claimed by stub
```

Here is the output of `lscpi -nn | nvidia`:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 [GeForce GTX 970] [10de:13c2] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:0fbb] (rev a1)
```

I can only stub the audio device.

I've attempted blacklisting NVIDIA and reloading later in initramfs as per the following link:

https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Multiheaded-NVIDIA-Gaming-using-Ubuntu-14-04-KVM-585/

I've also added the pci-stub entry to grub as per:

[Blacklist a Nvidia gpu for qemu/kvm passthrough](https://askubuntu.com/questions/719390/blacklist-a-nvidia-gpu-for-qemu-kvm-passthrough)

I am trying to pass 1 of my 2 Nvidia cards into a VM.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I changed the driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau to nvidia with the driver manager and after the restart the card was claimed by stub.